# Not able to write Jasmine test case for Controller in ANgularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-controller

I have following code in my controller and I want to write Jasmine test case for this part. 
    I tried to write one, but its throwing following error 
        TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'then'

Controller Code ::

```
$scope.doGetList = function() {
                var queryString = {......sending some query parameters};
                searchResource.getList(queryString).then(
                    function (data) {
                        $scope.sugesstions = data;
                    }
                );
            };
```

Jasmine Test Case ::

```
it("should return provided list", angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
                            var scope = $rootScope.$new();

                            var searchResource = {
                                getList: function() {
                                    return ['suggestions1', 'suggestions2', 'suggestions3'];
                                }
                            };

                            $controller(
                                    headerController,
                                    {
                                        $scope: scope,
                                        cartsService: null,
                                        currentUser: null,
                                        searchResource: searchResource
                                    }
                            );

                            expect(scope.sugesstions).toBeDefined();
                            expect(scope.sugesstions.length).toBe(0);

                            //this method will call mock method instead of actual server call
                            scope.doGetAutocomplete();
                            expect(scope.sugesstions.length).toBe(3);
                            expect(scope.sugesstions[0]).toEqual('suggestions1');
                            expect(scope.sugesstions[1]).toEqual('suggestions2');
                            expect(scope.sugesstions[2]).toEqual('suggestions3');
                        }));
```

How should I write it.

Comment: I am still not able to crack this out... Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to wrap async call in runs(). From jasmine doc: http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Asynchronous_Support

Or, I use jasmine-as-promised with better support: https://github.com/ThomasBurleson/jasmine-as-promised

Comment: I am not sure about how to use it. If there is any sample code then that would be helpful

Comment: aren't there examples in both links?

Comment: But those example are different and not very helpful to this scenario